# How can I manage the customization of a basic company product using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, customization

I need to simulate something similar to what I did for NestJS to customize a basic product for a specific customer.

For the backend, written in NestJS, I developed a feature that gets all modules inside a folder called "Plugin" and loads them inside the whole application at startup.

This is because my company sells basic software to N customers, but some of these customers may need more functionalities/customizations.

So at the moment I can provide more controllers/services by adding a folder inside the Plugin folder of my backend server.

By doing so I can have a unique repository of the backend where I can continue providing basic modules updates (the ones that every customer have).

The plugins are in a separate repositories.

Now I need to do the same thing for the frontends, so provide custom pages/components/navigation.

For the navigation it's not a problem, at frontend first load I can ask a JSON that tells me how to build/which elements are present inside the navigation sidebar.

But how can I provide the custom page (so HTML, TS, SCSS) connected to a menu item of the sidebar?

Comment: If you mean configurations, you should have a look at APP_INITIALIZER injection token of Angular: https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: @FatihErsoy I didn't talk about configurations, I talk about component/modules at runtime, it's possible for backend since it is a nodejs' process. I asked how to do with angular that isn't a nodejs process in production environment but it's compiled javascript, html, css

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guys, there is no code omg.. I think the concept is easy, I try to explain again:
Since Angular in production is simply html + js + css (compiled from a node process), I need a help to think how can I implement a sort of "plugin" feature, in order to have a customized client for every customer I have to provide the common  pages (common between customers) and customized pages (owned by a single customer)